# How to correctly ensure type safety on onChange method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Cat {
  type: string;
  Age: number;
}

type CatValue = Cat[keyof Cat];

const onChange(key: keyof Cat, value: CatValue) {
   // 
}
```

How can I ensure that type safety happens dependant on the key that is passed?

For example:

```
onChange('type', 'Short Haired Domestic'); // correct
onChange('type', 3); // correct, BUT it shouldnt be as the 'type' key should only accept strings.
```

Comment: you can check type as typeof value==="string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic can help us establish a relationship between `key` and `value`:

```
interface Cat {
  type: string;
  Age: number;
}

declare const cat: Cat;

const onChange = <K extends keyof Cat>(key: K, value: Cat[K]) => {
   cat[key] = value;
}
```